# How can I make this program more efficient

Tags: python

This program is a basic encoder in python and I want to see if I can make it more efficient without changing the names of the defined variables. Can someone give me some suggestions?

```
def encode(pattern, filename): 
  f = open(filename, "rt")
  contents = f.read()
  f.close()
  printNow(contents)

  changes = pattern.split("|")
  for str in changes: 
    printNow("Change "+ str[0] + " to " + str[1])

  newMsg = ""
  for char in contents:
     for change in changes:
       if char == change [0]:
         char = change[1]
     newMsg += char 



  f = open(filename + "encoded", "wt")
  f.write(newMsg)
  f.close()

  f = open(filename + "encoded", "rt")
  printNow(f.read())
  f.close()

encode("ae|ga|s3", "C:\\Users\\Shaun\\Desktop\\Test.txt")
```

Comment: You could start by measuring it and telling us where it's not performing as well as you think it should.

Comment: What do you mean by more efficient? You have to be more specific. The definition of Efficient varies form person to another, is ti the execution time, or the memory consumption, or the output??

Answer (score 3):

```
import string


def encode(pattern, filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        contents = f.read()
    s = string.maketrans(*[''.join(a) for a in zip(*pattern.split('|'))])
    newMsg = contents.translate(s)
    with open(filename + 'encoded', 'rt') as f:
        f.write(newMsg)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`str.translate()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) instead of doing all the replacements the hard way, and do it line-by-line.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to consider the option that your algorithm is already good enough. Even if it can be optimized, if your code is part of a bigger program and it only executes during 0.1% of time, for instance, then it will be most probably useless to optimize the code, since the rest of the program will dominate the total execution time.

If you really have a problem in your code, then I would start by analyzing the [complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) of your algorithm.

And finally, you could try to find some bottlenecks in your code. For that, I would profile the code with something like python's [timeit](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html).

Answer (score 0):

The str.translate() method works well for character substitutions, but here's another fast way I've used that also works for multi-character substitutions:

```
import re

def encode(pattern, filename): 
  f = open(filename, "rt")
  contents = f.read()
  f.close()
  printNow(contents)

  change_dict = {}
  matches = []
  changes = pattern.split("|")
  for str in changes: 
    printNow("Change "+ str[0] + " to " + str[1])
    change_dict[str[0]] = str[1]
    matches.append(str[0])

  change_re = re.compile("|".join(re.escape(x) for x in matches))

  newMsg = change_re.sub(lambda m: change_dict[m.group(0)], contents)

  f = open(filename + "encoded", "wt")
  f.write(newMsg)
  f.close()

  f = open(filename + "encoded", "rt")
  printNow(f.read())
  f.close()

encode("ae|ga|s3", "C:\\Users\\Shaun\\Desktop\\Test.txt")
```